# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException Xcode 9.1 / iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-x

my app works perfectly on my iPhone device and iPad, as well as all simulators and iOS except on the iPhone X simulator... It crashes out before the app starts with the following error log;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001127aa1ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011078af41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001127e9f9c _CFThrowFormattedException + 194
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126beb41 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 321
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011281d11b __createDictionary + 43
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112728cff +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:forKey:] + 47
    6   ChristmasCountdown                  0x000000010dc776a4 -[Home viewDidLoad] + 20900
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000115cb38a5 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1235
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000115cfb1ec -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 68
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000115cfb528 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 153
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000115cfc63f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 841
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000115cfd8c3 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000115f56a49 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000115bdf6f5 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b933ee -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 153
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b974dd _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b1fded _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 365
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b4b704 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000115b29d3a __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 141
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011274d18c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011273196b __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 203
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112731144 __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001127309b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011467a9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000115b0e5e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
    25  ChristmasCountdown                  0x000000010dc724df main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011594fd81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What I don't understand, is that the other simulators, work fine, phone and pad, and the same iOS version (11.1) so it seems specific to iPhoneX only...

viewDidLoad;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tag = 1000;
    str_Type = @"Current";

    //Set Navigation Bar Title
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = @"Christmas Countdown";
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;

    //Hide Not Required UILabel's
    lbl_Time.hidden = YES;
    lbl_Text.hidden = YES;
    lbl_Days.hidden = YES;
    lbl_DaysText.hidden = YES;
    lbl_Weeks.hidden = YES;
    lbl_WeeksText.hidden = YES;
    img_DividerImage.hidden = YES;

    //Initialize NSArray object with Images
    arr_OfSanta = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa1"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa2"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa3"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa4"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa5"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"santa6"]];

    //Initialize arr_MusicFiles & arr_MusicText Array
    arr_MusicFiles = @[@"auld-lang-syne-piano",@"ave-maria",@"away-in-a-manger-epiano",@"carol-of-the-bells",@"come-from-stars",@"ding-dong-merrily",@"god-rest-ye-merry-gentlemen",@"herald",@"jingle-bells-country",@"joy-to-the-world",@"o-christmas-tree",@"o-come-all-ye-faithful",@"o-holy-night",@"silent-night-piano",@"we-wish-you-a-merry-christmas"];

    arr_MusicText = @[@"Auld Land Syne Piano",@"Ave Maria",@"Away In A Manger Epiano",@"Carol Of the Bells",@"Come From Stars",@"Ding Dong Merrily",@"God Rest ye Merry Gentlemen",@"Herald",@"Jingle Bells Country",@"Joy To the World",@"O Christmas Tree",@"O Come All Ye Faithful",@"O Holy Night",@"Silent Night Piano",@"We Wish You A Merry Christmas"];

    arr_OfCountryCode = @[@"AF",@"AL",@"DZ",@"AS",@"AD",@"AO",@"AI",@"AQ",@"AG",@"AR",@"AM",@"AW",@"AC",@"AU",@"AT",@"AZ",@"BS",@"BH",@"BD",@"BB",@"BY",@"BE",@"BZ",@"BJ",@"BM",@"BT",@"BO",@"BA",@"BW",@"BV",@"BR",@"IO",@"VG",@"BN",@"BG",@"BF",@"BI",@"KH",@"CM",@"CA",@"IC",@",CV",@"BQ",@"KY",@"CF",@"EA",@"TD",@"CL",@"CN",@"CX",@"CP",@"CC",@"CO",@"KM",@"CD",@"CG",@"CK",@"CR",@"HR",@"CU",@"CW",@"CY",@"CZ",@"CI",@"DK",@"DG",@"DJ",@"DM",@"DO",@"EC",@"EG",@"SV",@"GQ",@"ER",@"EE",@"ET",@"FK",@"FO",@"FJ",@"FI",@"FR",@"FG",@"PF",@"TF",@"GA",@"GM",@"GE",@"DE",@"GH",@"GI",@"GR",@"GL",@"GD",@"GP",@"GU",@"GT",@"GG",@"GN",@"GW",@"GY",@"HT",@"HM",@"HN",@"HK",@"HU",@"IS",@"IN",@"ID",@"IR",@"IQ",@"IE",@"IM",@"IL",@"IT",@"JM",@"JP",@"JE",@"JO",@"KZ",@"KE",@"KI",@"XK",@"KW",@"KG",@"LA",@"LV",@"LB",@"LS",@"LR",@"LY",@"LI",@"LT",@"LU",@"MO",@"MK",@"MG",@"MW",@"MY",@"MV",@"ML",@"MT",@"MH",@"MQ",@"MR",@"MU",@"YT",@"MX",@"FM",@"MD",@"MC",@"MN",@"ME",@"MS",@"MA",@"MZ",@"MM",@"NA",@"NR",@"NP",@"NL",@"NC",@"NZ",@"NI",@"NE",@"NG",@"NU",@"NF",@"KP",@"MP",@"NO",@"OM",@"PK",@"PW",@"PS",@"PA",@"PG",@"PY",@"PE",@"PH",@"PN",@"PL",@"PT",@"PR",@"QA",@"RO",@"RU",@"RW",@"RE",@"WS",@"SM",@"SA",@"SN",@"RS",@"SC",@"SL",@"SG",@"SX",@"SK",@"SI",@"SB",@"SO",@"ZA",@"GS",@"KR",@"SS",@"ES",@"LK",@"BL",@"SH",@"KN",@"LC",@"MF",@"PM",@"VC",@"SD",@"SR",@"SJ",@"SZ",@"SE",@"CH",@"SY",@"ST",@"TW",@"TJ",@"TZ",@"TH",@"TL",@"TG",@"TK",@"TO",@"TT",@"TA",@"TN",@"TR",@"TM",@"TC",@"TV",@"UM",@"VI",@"UG",@"UA",@"AE",@"GB",@"US",@"UY",@"UZ",@"VU",@"VA",@"VE",@"VN",@"WF",@"EH",@"YE",@"ZM",@"ZW",@"AX"];

    //UIView Width
    int width = self.view.frame.size.width;

    //Current Device Model
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    //this will load wether or not they bought the in-app purchase
    areAdsRemoved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"areAdsRemoved"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    if ([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
        if(areAdsRemoved){
             [self.scrolView_Bottom setConstant:0];

            //Hide BannerView
            self.bannerView.hidden = YES;
            self.btn_RemoveAds.hidden = YES;
            //if they did buy it, set the background to blue.

        } else {

            [self.scrolView_Bottom setConstant:100];

            //Display BannerView
            self.bannerView.hidden = NO;
        }

        //Set UIScrollView Content Size
        self.srl_ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 365);
        self.srl_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6*width, 365);
        [self scrollViewDidScroll:self.srl_ScrollView];

        //Set Font Text Size
        objFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];

        //Adjust Constraints
        [self.view_Bottom setConstant:100];
        [self.img_Top setConstant:140];
        [self.btnLeft_Width setConstant:150];
        [self.btnLeft_Height setConstant:200];
        [self.btnRight_Height setConstant:200];
        [self.btnRight_Width setConstant:150];
        [self.bannerView_Height setConstant:100];

        //Set UILabel Font Size
        lbl_AllDays.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
        lbl_AllHours.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
        lbl_AllMinutes.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
        lbl_AllSeconds.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
        lbl_Time.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:55];
        lbl_Text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:35];
        lbl_Weeks.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:55];
        lbl_WeeksText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:35];
        lbl_Days.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:55];
        lbl_DaysText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:35];

        //Add Images in UIScrollView
        self.img_ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        self.img_ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.img_ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.img_ImageView.image = [arr_OfSanta objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.srl_ScrollView addSubview:self.img_ImageView];
    } else {

        if(areAdsRemoved){
            //Adjust UIScrollView Constraint
            [self.scrolView_Bottom setConstant:0];

            //Hide BannerView
            self.bannerView.hidden = YES;

            self.btn_RemoveAds.hidden = YES;
            //if they did buy it, set the background to blue.
        } else {
            //Adjust UIScrollView Constraint
            [self.scrolView_Bottom setConstant:50];

            //Display BannerView
            self.bannerView.hidden = NO;
        }

        //Current Device Screen Size
        int height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

        //Set UILabelText Font Size, If Screen height 480
        if (height == 480) {
            //Set Font Text Size
            objFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9.0];

            //Set UIScrollView Content Size
            self.srl_ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 150);
            self.srl_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6*width, 150);

            //Adjust Constraints
            [self.img_Top setConstant:50];

            //Set UILabel Font Size
            lbl_AllDays.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            lbl_AllHours.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            lbl_AllMinutes.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            lbl_AllSeconds.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
            lbl_Time.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
            lbl_Text.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            lbl_Weeks.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
            lbl_WeeksText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            lbl_Days.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
            lbl_DaysText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        }

        //Change Divider Image Top, When screen size grater than 480
        if (height == 568) {
            //Set Font Text Size
            objFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9.0];

            //Set UIScrollView Content Size
            self.srl_ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 150);
            self.srl_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6*width, 150);

            [self.img_Top setConstant:70];
        } else if (height == 667) {
            //Set UIScrollView Content Size
            self.srl_ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 240);
            self.srl_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6*width, 240);

            //Set Font Text Size
            objFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
            [self.img_Top setConstant:90];
        } else if (height == 736) {
            //Set UIScrollView Content Size
            self.srl_ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 270);
            self.srl_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6*width, 270);

            objFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
            [self.img_Top setConstant:100];
        }

        //Add Images in UIScrollView
        self.img_ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        self.img_ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.img_ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.img_ImageView.image = [arr_OfSanta objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.srl_ScrollView addSubview:self.img_ImageView];
    }

    //Hide MKMapView
    self.mapView.hidden = YES;

    //Zoom In & Zoom Out Animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        lbl_AllDays.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
        lbl_AllHours.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
        lbl_AllMinutes.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
        lbl_AllSeconds.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        // Finished scaling down imageview, now resize it
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
            lbl_AllDays.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            lbl_AllHours.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            lbl_AllMinutes.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            lbl_AllSeconds.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            NSLog(@";Finished...");
        }];
    }];

    //Set NSTimer to Call countdownTracker method to show pending time in Christmas.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(countdownTracker:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    //Add font object to Dictionary
    NSDictionary *dictAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    //Set dictionary to the titleTextAttributes
    [self.segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:dictAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.segmentControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    //Customize UISegmentControl
    [self.segmentControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigatinBackground"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //Customize MKMapView to track Santa Location
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    cl_LocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    cl_LocationManager.delegate = self;
    cl_LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    //[cl_LocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [cl_LocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //Hide UIView's mapView
    self.mapView.hidden = YES;
    self.musicView.hidden = YES;

}
```

This line causes the crash on iPhone X

```
 //Add font object to Dictionary
        NSDictionary *dictAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
```

Comment: Post the code of your `Home` class

Comment: There are a lot of lines in it, any particular code segment in particular?

Comment: Clearly the error is in the `viewDidLoad` method of your `Home` class. Update your question with `viewDidLoad` and point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: Done, now updated with `viewDidLoad` included

Comment: I have now pinpointed the exact line, if I comment it out, the app loads, but I am not sure if that is a viable solution.

The line is 

`NSDictionary *dictAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];`

Comment: That means that `objFont` is `nil`. Use the debugger and see why.

Comment: Figured it out! Have updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary *dictAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
```

This line is causing the crash because `objFont` is `nil`.

Why?
Because that's what you do:

```
if (somethingA)
{
    objFont = someFont;
}
else if (somethingB)
{
    objFont = someFont;
}
else if (somethingC)
{
    objFont = someFont;
}
//... others else if
else if (somethingN)
{
    objFont = someFont;
}

NSDictionary *dictAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
```

What you are missing is that if you never pass an if/else if test, obj font will never be initialized and cause the crash.

```
else if (somethingN)
{
    objFont = someFont;
}
else 
{
    objFont = someDefaultFont;
}
```

Or initialize `objFont` at start when you declare it.

For the rest, your code seems really messy. It could be improved, you shouldn't test like that the `height` to guess the Model.
You can also add the test "else if (height is the one of iPhone X), but that's not ugly) because if tomorrow Apple has a new phone with a new height, your code will crash again for an unmanaged case, so do the "else" or the default init.

Answer (score 1):

Inside my code, you can see hard coded font values, such as;

```
if (height == 568) {
            //Set Font Text Size
            objFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9.0];

            //Set UIScrollView Content Size
            self.srl_ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 150);
            self.srl_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6*width, 150);
```

Adding an entry specific to iPhone X size works perfectly;

```
//iPhoneX
    } else if (height == 812) {
        //Set UIScrollView Content Size
        self.srl_ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.srl_ScrollView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, 270);
        self.srl_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(6*width, 270);

        objFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
        [self.img_Top setConstant:100];
    }
```